# Can pmovmskb have a 64-bit destination?

Tags: assembly, x86

Using NASM version 2.11.08, the following compiles just fine:

```
pmovmskb eax, mm0
```

But the following is rejected with *error: invalid combination of opcode and operands*:

```
pmovmskb rax, mm0
```

I don't understand why this isn't legal?  In the Intel manual, the operation line just says **PMOVMSKB reg, mm**, but the *Operation* section includes explanations of both:

- PMOVMSKB (with 64-bit source operand and r32)
- PMOVMSKB (with 64-bit source operand and r64)

So that makes me think I should be able to run it with EAX or RAX as the destination, right?  But maybe there's something I don't understand...?

Comment: Since the top 32 bits are automatically cleared you should encode the 32 bit registers even if you really want 64 bit. GNU assembler automatically does this for you, but apparently nasm doesn't.

Comment: Is the problem specific to using an MMX (not xmm/ymm) register?  Intel's insn ref manual says the default operand size is 64, in 64bit mode, so it sounds like rax is the "right" choice.  YASM assembles the rax and eax versions the same way (`(66) 0f d7 c0`), and objdump disassembles the insn back to eax, with either mm0 or xmm0 as a source.

Comment: To Jester, I understand that either way the instruction should result in the same value being written to the whole register.  However I am curious as to whether these are in any way different instructions (different encoding, etc.), and whether they should both be permitted.  To Peter, it appears to me that the XMM case is similar, and requires EAX to be specified for some reason.

Comment: Probably yasm requires you to tell it you really want the longer encoding.  If you write `mov eax, [rsi + 0]`, it actually uses the addressing mode with no offset at all.  I assume that a `48` prefix would work for the xmm version, like Hans found in his answer.  Perhaps the Intel manual's statement that the default operand size is 64b is one of its many bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just show you the output of my debugger when I try your code, generated by ml64.exe:

```
.CODE
testfunc PROC
    pmovmskb eax, mm0
00007FF78A611060 0F D7 C0             pmovmskb    eax,mm0  
    pmovmskb rax, mm0
00007FF78A611063 48 0F D7 C0          pmovmskb    rax,mm0  
    ret
00007FF78A611067 C3                   ret
```

---

Verifying that it is not a bug in that assembler with [this site](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/):

[image]

---

Well, MMX is definitely a step-child, best to ignore that it ever existed.  You can report a bug with the project at [this page](http://bugzilla.nasm.us/).